# how to manipulate further the list created from group_map() in R dplyr

Tags: r, list, group-by, dplyr

I am fairly new with R and I use the old-school for-loop. I'm trying to code more efficiently by using dplyr to make the processing of my data faster but I am ever confused with lists. I have a simple dataset below:

```
df <- data_frame(group = sort(rep(1:3, 20)), 
                  values = signif(runif(60), 2),
                  thresh = ifelse(values > 0.6, TRUE, FALSE))

df %>% group_by(group) %>% group_map(~which(.$thresh == TRUE))
```

From the output of `group_map()` above, how do I, 1.) create a new column that contains row names of `thresh == TRUE` only and the rest are NA, and 2.) create another column that contains the maximum value among the TRUE values from `thresh`. To illustrate, I desire my final dataframe to be somewhat like this:

```
   group values  thresh idex  max
 1     1 0.77    TRUE    1    NA
 2     1 0.32    FALSE   NA   NA
 3     1 0.06    FALSE   NA   NA
 4     1 0.33    FALSE   NA   NA
 5     1 0.51    FALSE   NA   NA
 6     1 0.053   FALSE   NA   NA
 7     1 0.92    TRUE    7    0.92
 8     1 0.44    FALSE   NA   NA
...
...
```

I thought about making a code but I'm stuck after `group_map`:

```
dff %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  group_map(~which(.$thresh == TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(idex = *row_names_in_the_column_blank_are_NA*,
         max = max(*values_from_the_indices*))
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  #For each group
  group_by(group) %>% 
         #Give row number to TRUE thresh values and NA to FALSE thresh values
  mutate(idex = replace(row_number(), !thresh, NA), 
         #Get maximum of values where thresh == TRUE
         max_v = max(values[thresh],na.rm = TRUE), 
         #Replace values to NA where the value is not maximum. 
         max_v = replace(max_v, max_v != values, NA))
```

---

Here's a way to make it work with `group_map`

```
df %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% group_by(group) %>% group_map(~{
            tibble(idex = replace(seq_along(.x$thresh), !.$thresh, NA), 
                   max_v1 = max(.x$values[.x$thresh],na.rm = TRUE), 
                   max_v = replace(max_v1, max_v1 != .x$values, NA)) %>%
             select(-max_v1)
             }) %>%
             bind_rows())
```

Comment: If we stick with using `group_map`, how can the output  list be used? The reason I insist the question is my confusion about breaking down sub-lists from groups... does that make sense?

Comment: @mand3rd sorry, why do you want to use `group_map` specifically here? I think using `group_by` and `mutate` is straightforward to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this particular solution is straightforward. In my original data, I am using a function I made to extract some values (local maxima to be specific) that creates a list. I think I over-simplified my example...

Comment: @mand3rd Updated the answer to make it work with `group_map`, not sure if it helps.